# navbar collapse --> Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm building a website: http://www.sbr-accounting.com/

and now I have my menu responsive. So when you decrease the width of the screen the menu will dissapear and only a Menu button will be shown. Great!

But how come that when I open the website on Iphone (5S) the menu is shown fully, I expected the menu will be shown collapsed as default.

Can anyone help me out here?

```
  <!-- Create full width navbar -->
    <div class='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top'>

      <!-- Inside full width navbar create a container -->
      <div class='container'>

        <div class='navbar-header'>
          <!-- Website title including home link -->
          <a href='index.html' class='navbar-brand'>SBR-accounting</a>


          <!-- Create nav icon for small displays. The text should only be visible for screen readers -->
          <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>  <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>    

          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          </button>
         </div>

          <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse'>
            <li><a href='/'>home</a></li>
            <li><a href='/'>Informatie</a></li>
            <li><a href='/'>Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div> <!-- Close container inside navbar -->
      </div> <!-- Close full width navbar -->
```

Comment: But the thing is you have put the container inside the navbar div which always creates the problems

Comment: it's inside al ready, isn't it?

Comment: Try wrapping the whole `navbar` inside a `container` and `col-xs-12` grid.

Comment: Doesn't work @TusharKhatiwada

Comment: If I starting to create a new website, I use this website [initializr](http://www.initializr.com/). It saves time and you cannot make this mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked your code, by desktop and mobile.
In the `<head>` tag, you are missing the viewport `<meta>` tag.

From Bootstrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile)

> With Bootstrap 2, we added optional mobile friendly styles for key
>   aspects of the framework. With Bootstrap 3, we've rewritten the
>   project to be mobile friendly from the start. Instead of adding on
>   optional mobile styles, they're baked right into the core. In fact,
>   Bootstrap is mobile first. Mobile first styles can be found throughout
>   the entire library instead of in separate files.
>
> To ensure proper rendering and touch zooming, add the viewport meta
>   tag to your `<head>`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#Viewport_basics) you can find a little explanation about viewport basics. From there I've extrapolated this explanation:

> The width property controls the size of the viewport. It can be set to
>   a specific number of pixels like width=600 or to the special value
>   device-width value which is the width of the screen in CSS pixels at a
>   scale of 100%. (There are corresponding height and device-height
>   values, which may be useful for pages with elements that change size
>   or position based on the viewport height.)
>
> The initial-scale property controls the zoom level when the page is
>   first loaded. The maximum-scale, minimum-scale, and user-scalable
>   properties control how users are allowed to zoom the page in or out.